# is there another way for a pop up in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

what i want to happen is that when i click my button it shows a pop up like snack bar or an alert but none of that is happening.When the button is clicked it shows the selected doctor and date but it does not show a the snack bar or even the pop.I would appreciate it if this could be fixed.

This is my code

```
function Appointments({ onAppointmentSelection }) {

  const handleScheduleAppointment = (e) => {
    const appointment = {
      doctor: doctors.find((d) => d.name === doctor).name,
      appointmentDate: new Date(appointmentDate),
    };
    setAppointments([...appointments, appointment]);
    onAppointmentSelection(appointment);
    console.log('handleScheduleAppointment');
    alert("Appointment scheduled successfully!"); 
  };

  const handleCloseSnackbar = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setShowSuccessMessage(false);
  };
  function formatDate(date) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = `${date.getMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, '0');
    const day = `${date.getDate()}`.padStart(2, '0');
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  }

  return (
    <div className='classes.root'>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Appointments
      </Typography>
      <form className='classes.form'>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className='classes.button'
          disabled={!doctor || !appointmentDate}
          onClick={() => {
            handleScheduleAppointment();
            setShowSuccessMessage(true);
          }}
        >
          Schedule Appointment
        </Button>
      </form>
      <Snackbar
        open={showSuccessMessage}
        autoHideDuration={3000} // Hides the message after 5 seconds
        onClose={handleCloseSnackbar}
        message="Appointment scheduled successfully!"
        sx={{ bottom: '50px' }} // sets the position of the snackbar message
      />
    </div>
   )
}
export default Appointments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using states that are required based on the events you are calling. Apart from this, Instead of handling snackbar with such a way you can use npm library called [react-hot-toast](https://react-hot-toast.com/). It comes out real handy for such use cases.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Button, Snackbar } from "@material-ui/core";

function Appointments({ onAppointmentSelection }) {
  const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = React.useState(false);

  const handleCloseSnackbar = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setShowSuccessMessage(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="classes.root">
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Appointments
      </Typography>
      <form className="classes.form">
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className="classes.button"
          // disabled={!doctor || !appointmentDate}
          onClick={() => {
            setShowSuccessMessage(true);
          }}
        >
          Schedule Appointment
        </Button>
      </form>
      <Snackbar
        open={showSuccessMessage}
        autoHideDuration={3000} // Hides the message after 5 seconds
        onClose={handleCloseSnackbar}
        message="Appointment scheduled successfully!"
        sx={{ bottom: "50px" }} // sets the position of the snackbar message
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Appointments;
```